# Change the LinkedList class into a generic collection similar to the java.util.ArrayList class

Tags: java, linked-list, generic-collections

This is a `LinkedList` that have methods to modify the list. One of the things I have to do is:

> Change the LinkedList class into a generic collection similar to the `java.util.ArrayList` class.

I don't know how to do that?

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

/**
A linked list is a sequence of nodes with efficient
element insertion and removal. This class 
contains a subset of the methods of the standard
java.util.LinkedList class.
 */
public class LinkedList<E>
{  
   int currentSize =0;
    private Node head;
    private Node tail;

    /** 
    Constructs an empty linked list.
     */
    public LinkedList()
    {  
        head = null;
        tail = null;
    }

    /**
    Adds an element to the front of the linked list.
    @param element the element to add
     */
    public void addFirst(Object element)
    {  
        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.data = element;
        newNode.next = head;
        currentSize++;
        head = newNode;
        tail = head;
        while( tail.next != null)
        {
         tail = tail.next;
        }
    }

    /**
    Removes the head element in the linked list.
    @return the removed element
     */
    public Object removeFirst()
    {  
        if (head == null) 
            throw new NoSuchElementException();

        Object temp = head.data;


        head = head.next;
         currentSize--;
        return temp;

    }

    /**
    Returns the head element in the linked list.
    @return the head element in the linked list
     */
    public Object getFirst()
    {  
        if (head == null) 
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        return head.data;
    }

    /**
    Returns the element at a given position in the linked list.
    @param index the element position
    @return the element at the given position
     */
    Object get(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();

        Node current = head;
        int i = 0;

        while (current != null && i < index)
        {
            current = current.next;
            i++;
        }

        if (current == null)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        return current.data;
    }

    /**
    Computes the size of the linked list
    @return the number of elements in the list
     */
    public int size()
    { 
        //to be completed for lab 7.1 #2
        return currentSize;  // rewrite this, just makes it compile
    }

    /**
    Reverses all elements in a linked list.
     */
    public void reverse()
    { 
        //to be completed for lab 7.1 #1
        if(head == null)
         throw new NoSuchElementException();
          tail = head;
         Node current = head;
         Node nextt= head.next;
        Node nul= null;

        while(nextt!= null)
        {
         current.next = nul;
         nul = current;
         current = nextt;
         nextt = nextt.next;
        }

        head = current;
        head.next = nul;

    }

    /**
    Adds an element to the end of the linked list.
    @param element the element to add
     */
    public void add(Object element)
    { 

        if(head==null)
       addFirst(element);

       else
        {
            Node newNode = new Node();
            newNode.data = element;
            newNode.next = null;
            tail.next = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
            currentSize++;
        }
        //to be completed for lab 7.1 #3
    }    

    /**
    Returns an iterator for iterating through this list.
    Allows the use of the iterator outside of this class.
    @return an iterator for iterating through this list
     */
    public ListIterator listIterator()
    {  
        return new LinkedListIterator();
    }

    /**
    Returns a string representation of this list in brackets 
    separated by commas.
    @return a string of list elements.
     */
    public String toString()
    {  
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
        ListIterator it = listIterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            temp.append(it.next());
            if(it.hasNext())
                temp.append(", ");
        }
        return temp.toString();    
    }

    private static class Node
    {  
        private Object data;
        private Node next;
    }

    private class LinkedListIterator implements ListIterator
    {              
        private Node position;
        private Node previous;

        /**
        Constructs an iterator that points to the front
        of the linked list.
         */
        public LinkedListIterator()
        {  
            position = null;
            previous = null;
        }

        /**
        Moves the iterator past the next element.
        @return the traversed element
         */
        public Object next()
        {  
            if (!hasNext())
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            previous = position; // Remember for remove

            if (position == null)
                position = head;
            else
                position = position.next;

            return position.data;
        }

        /**
        Tests if there is an element after the iterator 
        position.
        @return true if there is an element after the iterator 
        position
         */
        public boolean hasNext()
        {  
            if (position == null)
                return head != null;
            else
                return position.next != null;

        }

        /**
        Adds an element before the iterator position
        and moves the iterator past the inserted element.
        @param element the element to add
         */
        public void add(Object element)
        {  
            if (position == null)
            {
                addFirst(element);
                position = head;


            }
            else
            {  
                Node newNode = new Node();
                newNode.data = element;
                newNode.next = position.next;
                position.next = newNode;
                position = newNode;
                previous = position;
                tail=head;
                while( tail.next != null)
                {
                   tail = tail.next; 
                }
               currentSize++;
            }




        }

        /**
        Removes the last traversed element. This method may
        only be called after a call to the next() method.
         */
        public void remove()
        {  
            if (previous == position)
                throw new IllegalStateException();

            if (position == head)
            {
                removeFirst();

            }
            else 
            {  
                previous.next = position.next;
                tail=head;
                while(tail.next != null)
                {
                   tail = tail.next; 
                }
               currentSize--;
            }

           position = previous;

        }

        /**
        Sets the last traversed element to a different 
        data. 
        @param element the element to set
         */
        public void set(Object element)
        {
            if (position == null)
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            position.data = element;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to learn generics.

Answer (score 1):

They are both collections.

I believe you have to replace all instances of `Object` with `E` so that the java class can take the generic type it is declared with in the < >.